# Split Comma separated columns into more columns but in order - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like this:

| key | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2030804 | 1,2 | 9,8 |
| 3429534 | 4,5,6 | 1,2,3 |

I want my output to be:

| key | A1 | B1 | A2 | B2 | A3 | B3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2030804 | 1 | 9 | 2 | 8 |  |  |
| 3429534 | 4 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 6 | 3 |

How can I do this in Pandas? Assume that I have n number of columns and n number of rows.

Comment: Your question can be improved by following the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Can you provide a DataFrame constructor?

Comment: @mozway: import pandas as pd

# Sample data
data = {
    'key': [2030804, 3429534],
    'A': ['1,2', '4,5,6'],
    'B': ['9,8', '1,2,3']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can have more than 2 columns to be processed, you can create a function that creates a separate dataframe for each column and then concat them together with key column:

```
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "key": [2030804, 3429534],
    "A": ["1,2", "4,5,6"],
    "B": ["9,8", "1,2,3"],
})

def get_column_split(df, column_name):
    list_data = df[column_name].str.split(",").tolist()
    n_columns = max(map(len, list_data))
    columns = [f"{column_name}{i}" for i in range(1, n_columns + 1)]
    
    return pd.DataFrame(list_data, columns=columns)

new_df = pd.concat(
    [df[["key"]]] + [get_column_split(df, column_name) for column_name in df.columns[1:]],
    axis=1
)
new_df[
    sorted(new_df.columns.values, key=lambda x: (re.findall("\d+", x), x))
]
```

Output:

```
       key A1 B1 A2 B2    A3    B3
0  2030804  1  9  2  8  None  None
1  3429534  4  1  5  2     6     3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
out = (df.set_index('key').stack()
         .str.extractall('([^,]+)')[0]
         .unstack([-2, -1])
       )
out.columns= out.columns.map(lambda s: f'{s[0]}{s[1]+1}')
```

Variant with [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
(df.set_index('key').stack()
   .str.split(',', expand=True)
   .stack()
   .unstack([-2, -1])
 )
out.columns= out.columns.map(lambda s: f'{s[0]}{s[1]+1}')
```

Output:

```
        A1 A2 B1 B2   A3   B3
key                          
2030804  1  2  9  8  NaN  NaN
3429534  4  5  1  2    6    3
```

Comment: @gara had you a chance to test this approach?